# set asymmetric bandwidth on an interface

Tags: bandwidth, tc

I'm coding a simple application using docker-compose and docker networks (images based on ubuntu). One of my services is a client with a network interface given from docker. All my services are on my machine (client,server,db, for debugging purposes of course) and I would like to recreate an asymmetric bandwidth on the client service. What I've done so far is the following:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev " + dock_cli_iface + " root tbf rate 1mbit burst 32kbit latency 400ms
```

Here, `dock_cli_iface` is just a placeholder. This works fine, but it gives me a symmetric bandwidth. How can I set 2 different bandwidth for up and down? For example, what should I have to issue to get 1Mbit (up) and 2Mbit(down). I don't need a very accurate simulation.

*I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question so, if this is not please tell me on whick stack site I should upload this question.*